# Moving image with OpenGl and Updating screen?

Tags: android, image, opengl-es

I have created an OpenGl renderer:

```
package com.jump.nuttyjump;

public class GlRenderer implements Renderer {
private Sprite square; // the square
private Context context;

public GlRenderer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    //Sprites
    this.square = new Sprite();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    // Draw all Sprites
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
    square.draw(gl); // Draw the triangle
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) { // Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1; // Making Height Equal One
    }
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix
    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f,
            100.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Modelview Matrix
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Load Textures for all Sprites:
    square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH); // Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f); // Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f); // Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL); // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
}
}
```

Now when i run this, it displays the image that i loaded in just fine. However i dont know how to make it move.

How would i go about moving the image that i loaded in, and then "repainting" the view, much like you would with a canvas?

Comment: Did you start reading any OpenGL tutorials ?

Comment: I read all of the ones i could find, and they are all incomplete and not very useful for what im asking.

Comment: Well, when you loadidentity, you return to the origin, next you tell the OpenGL to move to 0,0,-5; Every frame will draw the same picture
I suggest you using a temporary variable holding current location of the box and update it everyframe, then translate to that temp variable

Comment: So i need to create a runnable or a thread and call onDrawFrame from that?

Comment: I didn't use OpenGL with java before, isn't OnDrawFrame looping itself ? i.e. called everyframe

Comment: Yes it is. SO if i change the variable from 5 to something else, it will move?

Comment: for example to (x, 0 , -5)
and everyframe increase x by 0.1 or so